# About characterizations of Euclidean Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

Recently I found a theorem about Bézout domains (BD) and it says that an integral domain $D$ is a PID (principal ideal domain) iff $D$ is both an UFD (unique factorization domain) and a BD.

> So I was wondering if there is an analogous result if we replace PID by *euclidean domain* (ED). More exactly, is there a theorem that says something like: $$ED \iff UFD + (\text{some special domain})\; \text{or}\\ ED \iff BD + (\text{some special domain})\;?$$

Well, after some googling I haven't found anything and it seems, as Hans Lundmark points out, that there is no such a characterization of euclidean domains. Is this related to the fact that UFDs and BDs have characterizations by ideal theoretic conditions whereas euclidean domains, as follows from this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15354/97665), do not have it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very likely. At least none of the commonly encountered types of integral domains will work (Dedekind, Prüfer, Noetherian, ACCP, Krull, GCD, Schreier, atomic, integrally closed, ...).